# What version code comes after e.g v 1.0.9 for an android app

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Im a beginner in flutter development and i'm not very familiar with versioning of an app. i believe from version 1.0.9 it's supposed to be 1.0.10 but everytime i try to upload my new release i get an error that i already have a release with  version code 1. Whats could be the issue?

Comment: How do i change the version code (Flutter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**v 1.1.0** comes after **1.0.9**. Also make sure to change the version code.
if the current version is **1.0.9+10** , then you need to change it to **1.1.0+11**
where **+10** and **+11** is the version code.

Make these changes in the **pubspec.yaml** file. For example:

```
version: 1.1.0+11
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Version code of the app is updated before publishing the app

[image: Version Code]

Comment: How do i get to this modules tab?

Comment: Go to File >  Project Structure. then click on Module. If you are unable to find it here. You can change Code Version through build.gradle file as well.

Comment: I cant seem to find it. I guess different Studio version .im trying to avoid hard coding version in build.gradle coz im using flutter